# How Get Count in Join Query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.7

I want to convert the following SQL to Laravel.

```sql
SELECT COUNT('uc.*') AS count_down, bs.brand_name
FROM `user_activities` AS uc
    JOIN brands AS bs ON uc.brand_id = bs.id
GROUP BY uc.brand_id
ORDER BY count_down DESC
LIMIT 5
```

But when doing this:

```php
$top_donwload_list = DB::table('user_activities')
    ->leftJoin('brands', 'brands.id', '=', 'user_activities.brand_id')
    ->selectRaw('brands.*, brands.brand_name, brands.id, count(user_activities.action_type) as user_activitiesCount')
    ->groupBy('user_activities.brand_id')
    ->get();
```

I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'colorworld.brands.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select brands.*, brands.brand_name, brands.id, count(user_activities.action_type) as user_activitiesCount from `user_activities` left join `brands` on `brands`.`id` = `user_activities`.`brand_id` group by `user_activities`.`brand_id`)

I tried to set `'strict' => true`, in `database.php` but I get the same error in Laravel 5.7.

Update:- database table

[image: Brand Table]
[image: User activities]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to find the count of user activities grouped by a brand's name. Also you want the top 5 records ordered by the ones with the most user activities.

So, the following should work:

```
$top_donwload_list = DB::table('user_activities')
    ->selectRaw("brands.brand_name, COUNT('user_activities.*') as user_activitiesCount")
    ->join('brands', 'brands.id', '=', 'user_activities.brand_id')
    ->groupBy('brands.brand_name')
    ->orderBy('user_activitiesCount', 'desc')
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Yes, you right. but this query is not working got error "
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '*) as user_activitiesCount from `user_activities` inner join `brands` on `brands' at line 1 (SQL: select brands.name, COUNT(user_activities.*) as user_activitiesCount from `user_activities` inner join `brands` on `brands`.`id` = `user_activities`.`brand_id` group by `brands`.`name` order by `user_activitiesCount` desc limit 5)"

Comment: update your answare "brand.name" to "brand.brand_name"

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel Eloquent. I Assume that the relationship between brand and user_activities is one to many and Here, the "Brand" is the model of the brand entity.

```
$count = Brand::leftJoin
                 ('user_activities', function($join_brands){ 
                    $join_brands-> on 
                        ('brands.id', '=','user_activity.brand_id');
                 )->orderBy('user_activities.count_down','desc ')                     
                  ->groupBy('user_activities.brand_id')->count();
```

Comment: Please add a proper answer.